# How to nest Rails tag in a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 6.1, trying to nest content inside a helper method with:

```rb
tag.div do
  concat tag.span 'Options: ', class: 'small'
  concat tag.span do
    doc.options.each do
      concat option.title
    end
  end
end
```

I was expecting this to return a div with two spans inside it, the first of which has the "Options" string, the second of which has the titles for all the options. But this doesn't work.  I wind up with:

```
<div>
  <span class="small">Options: </span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

The last span is blank. How can I get this working?

Comment: Why are you using a helper and not html/partials? Also, what do you want the end result to be?

Comment: @CassandraS. - good question! Perhaps I'm getting away from what helpers are for.... Still, curious why this doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure there are options for the doc object?

Comment: @dbugger - yes. Have verified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is... I'm not entirely sure. There is some weird stuff going on between `concat` and `tag`, that's for sure:

```
:0> tag.div do
:1*   tag.span { "A" }
:1> end
=> "<div><span>A</span></div>"

# But:
:0>tag.div do
:1*   tag.span { "A" }
:1>   tag.span { "B" }
:1> end
=> "<div><span>B</span></div>"

# But also:
:0> tag.div do
:1*   concat tag.span { "A" }
:1>   concat tag.span { "B" }
:1> end
=> "<div><span></span><span></span></div>"

:0> helper.tag.div do
:1*   concat tag.span { concat "A" }
:1>   concat tag.span { concat "B" }
:1> end
=> "<div><span>A</span><span>B</span></div>"

# For completeness:
:0> tag.div do
:1*   concat tag.span "A"
:1>   concat tag.span "B"
:1> end
=> "<div><span>A</span><span>B</span></div>"
```

Perhaps someone better versed in Rails can explain it better. But I can offer you a solution.

---

Or rather, I don't know what you want to achieve, but you can do something like this:

```
tag.div do
  concat tag.span "A"
  concat tag.span([1, 2, 3].join(" "))
end
```

That will give you `<div><span>1 2 3</span></div>`. You can also do away with the concat entirely:

```
tag.div do
  tag.span "A"
  tag.span([1, 2, 3].join(" "))
end
```

But if you want each `title` as its own `span`, you're doing it the wrong way around:

```
:0> tag.div do
:1*   concat tag.span "A"
:1>   ["B", "C"].each { |c| concat tag.span c }
:1> end
=> "<div><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span></div>"
```

Finally; there's no reason to use a helper for this kind of static html; this would be better served in an erb or haml file:

```
<span class="small">Options</span>
<% doc.options.each do |option| %>
  <span><%= option.title %></span>
<% end %>
```